# Is it possible to get a list of people who have made commits to a particular file?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get a list of the number of people who have made a commit/contributed to a particular file?  I'm looking for this kind of output:

git {blah} test.txt

```
JohnDoe@example.com
JaneDoe@example.com
```

Where John and Jane are the only two people who have created/edited test.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git log`'s [`--pretty` parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) to format its output.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ae" test.txt
```

This gets you the email of the author of each commit on a separate line.

Comment: You can also add `| sort -u` to only get each email once.

Comment: Right. I read the question a little quickly and didn't realize that the two committers were different. Shell processing is of course an option.

Answer (score 4):

Use `git log` and extract the Author:

```
git log /path/to/file | grep ^Author: | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

(the `sort ...` pipeline counts the number of commits per author and sorts the list by the numbers).